# Windows Azure In-Role Cache - WARNING: <SimpleSendReceiveModule> DeadServerCallback Called

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have an Azure cloud service app that is comprised of a worker role (1 instance only) and a web role (multiple instances).  The web role is also where the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching's (version 2.2) in-role co-located cache cluster resides.  I have Azure diagnostics set up and in my WadLogsTable I see this pair of warnings every few minutes in production:

> WARNING:  DeadServerCallback Called, Server URI: [net.tcp://100.74.158.31:20005], Underlying exception - ; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event
>
> WARNING:  DeadServerCallback: Matches My Server, Cleaning Pending Requests; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

The net.tcp://100.74.158.31:20005 corresponds to one of the web roles.  The warnings sporatically alternate between the web roles (i.e. sometimes it says net.tcp://100.74.158.51:20005).

Notice that there is nothing after "Underlying exception - ".  There are also no related exceptions in the WadWindowsEventLogsTable (I know that Azure exception logging is working because I will occasionally see other exceptions in that table).  I believe I've also turned on all the Caching diagnostics that I could.

**So my issue is that I am seeing all these warnings but I don't know why and I don't know how to remedy the situation.  It doesn't appear that these warnings are causing the app to crash, but still they are worrisome.  Any help would be appreciated.**

Here is my ServiceConfiguration.cscfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ServiceConfiguration serviceName="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
      <Role name="WebRole">
        <Instances count="2" />
        <ConfigurationSettings>
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXX" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches" value="{&quot;caches&quot;:[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;default&quot;,&quot;policy&quot;:{&quot;eviction&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:0},&quot;expiration&quot;:{&quot;defaultTTL&quot;:10,&quot;isExpirable&quot;:true,&quot;type&quot;:2},&quot;serverNotification&quot;:{&quot;isEnabled&quot;:false}},&quot;secondaries&quot;:0}]}" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.DiagnosticLevel" value="3" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.CacheSizePercentage" value="30" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXX" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel" value="3" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="Me" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="XXXXX" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2014-08-05T23:59:59.0000000-07:00" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
        <Certificates>
          <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="XXXXX" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
          <Certificate name="www.myapp.com" thumbprint="XXXXX" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
        </Certificates>
      </Role>
      <Role name="WorkerRole">
        <Instances count="1" />
        <ConfigurationSettings>
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel" value="3" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="Me" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="XXXXX" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2014-08-05T23:59:59.0000000-07:00" />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
          <!-- For Windows Azure ServiceManagement. -->
          <Setting name="SubscriptionId" value="XXXXX" />
          <Setting name="ServiceManagementCertificateThumbprint" value="value="XXXXX" " />
          <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXX" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
        <Certificates>
          <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="XXXXX" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
          <!-- For Windows Azure ServiceManagement. -->
          <Certificate name="ServiceManagementCertificate" thumbprint="thumbprint="XXXXX" " thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
        </Certificates>
      </Role>
    </ServiceConfiguration>
```

Here are pertinent parts of the Web.config of my web role:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default" connectionPool="true" useLegacyProtocol="false" isCompressionEnabled="false" maxConnectionsToServer="2">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="WebRole" />
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>

<cacheDiagnostics>
    <crashDump dumpLevel="Full" dumpStorageQuotaInMB="100" scheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes="5" />
  </cacheDiagnostics>
```

Here are pertinent parts of the App.config of my worker role:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default" connectionPool="true" useLegacyProtocol="false" isCompressionEnabled="false" maxConnectionsToServer="2">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="WebRole" />
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
  <cacheDiagnostics>
    <crashDump dumpLevel="Full" dumpStorageQuotaInMB="100" scheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes="5" />
  </cacheDiagnostics>
```

Additional notes:

- I've probably tried every possible combination of attribute settings for both the `<dataCacheClient>` entries in the web role's
  Web.config and worker role's App.config.
- The cloud service has been upgraded to use Windows Azure Tools version 2.2.
- I've Googled and found a few posts related to these warnings but it seems that most people only experienced this in the compute emulator, not on production like I am.  Nevertheless, I've tried most of their suggested solutions and nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you dont see any failures or timeouts or drop in quality of the service, you should be good. The deadserver callback should be just cleaning up old unused connections. To validate this hypothesis :

Do you have any other connection errors happening in verbose logging ? Can you see if the last request to this server was a long time back ? Do you have bursty traffic ?